# How to solve the equation $k = \frac{dv}{dt}(a + 2\int_0^t v(\tau) d\tau)^2$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I've been struggling a little on this problem for a while. I'm not sure what I'm missing. It goes like this:

$$k = \frac{dv}{dt}(a + 2\int_0^t v(\tau) d\tau)^2$$

Here $k, a$ are constants and $v, t$ represent velocity and time respectively. I want to know $v$ as a function of $t$. Is it possible to solve this? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Suggestion: Try differentiating both sides and see if it reduces

Comment: Suggestion 2: Try replacing $\int ^{t}_{0} v( x) dx$ as $f(t)$ and then reducing the equation.

Answer (score 1):

Set $V(t)=\int_0^tv(s)ds$. Then your equation reads as
$$
k=V''(a+2V)^2.
$$
this can be separated and integrated once
$$
V''=\frac{k}{(a+2V)^2}\implies V'^2=c-\frac{k}{a+2V}.
$$
In principle you can now apply separation again, the resulting integral with square root might be difficult or impossible to solve.

Answer (score -2):

If $v$ is velocity and is given by $v=\frac{ds}{dt}$ then

$$\int_0^tv(\tau)d\tau=\int_0^t\frac{ds}{d\tau}d\tau$$

By the fundamental theorem of calculus and Leibniz's rule:

$$\int_0^t\frac{ds}{dt}d\tau=\frac{d}{dt}\int_0^tsd\tau=\frac{d}{dt}st=s$$

Note: We are only allowed to do this because these specific limits of integration(zero at the left part, variable/parameter on the right part)

Substituting back in the original equation:

Which is 1st order in $v$

$$k=\frac{dv}{dt}(a+2s)^2$$

But because $v$ depends on $s$ we need to integrate it wrt. to $s$, then it's a 2nd order linear ODE:

$$k=\frac{d^2s}{dt^2}(a+2s)^2$$

$$\iint kdtdt=\iint(a+2s)^2dsds$$

$$k\frac{t^2}{2}=\int \frac{(a+2s)^3}{3a}ds+C=\frac{(a+2s)^4}{4a^2}+C$$

Now solve for $s$ and differentiate wrt. $t$ get back your solution to $v$.

[Why doesn't distance depend on time?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_System_of_Quantities#Base_quantities)

To OP: try going through each step, i'll leave you to differentiate it on your own. Tell me if you got stuck.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I'm not sure I get how converting that integral to displacement helps in solving the problem. Could you provide a hint?

Comment: After solving with the integral you are left with a simple 1st order linear ODE. You can just integrate it.

Comment: @LordCommander Correction : A 2nd order ODE.

Comment: @LordCommander Doesn't s also depend on time? Then how is (a+2s) a constant?

Comment: @IshraaqParvez $s$ is a base unit, it doesn't depend on time, their quotient (velocity) does depend on time though.

Comment: $v(t)=\frac{s}{t}\neq s(t)$ It's easy to confuse them. To figure this one out imagine for example your house $x$ meters away from the neighbour's house. Does that distance change whether you measure it for 2 seconds or 2 hours?

Comment: The time-dependence was inside of $v$ which we just got rid of, $s$ does not depend on time.